# Create list that is a combination of two named lists in R

Tags: r

I have two lists in R:

```
variable_names <- list(
"WT" = expression(bolditalic("Zic2")^bolditalic("+/+")),
"HET" = expression(bolditalic("Zic2")^bolditalic("Ku/+")))

treat_names <- list(
"VEH" = "Vehicle",
"ETH" = "Ethanol")
```

Items within variable_names are expressions that need to be properly formatted.

Is there a way to combine these lists that makes the expressions still work and names each item similar to interaction()?

e.g. desired result:

```
comb_names <- list(
"WT.VEH" = expression(bolditalic("Zic2")^bolditalic("+/+")~bold("Vehicle")),
"HET.VEH" = expression(bolditalic("Zic2")^bolditalic("Ku/+")~bold("Vehicle")),
"WT.ETH" = expression(bolditalic("Zic2")^bolditalic("+/+")~bold("Ethanol")),
"HET.ETH" = expression(bolditalic("Zic2")^bolditalic("Ku/+")~bold("Ethanol")))
```

Kind Regards,

Dorky-Lever